# Getting rid of globals and creating functions

Tags: python, function, console, global

```
import subprocess as sp

plyr_x, plyr_y = (9,5)
plyr_char = 'o'

def create_board():
    ''' Creates a 10x10 grid of cells'''
    board = []
    for _ in range(10):
        board.append(['-']*10)
    board[plyr_x][plyr_y] = plyr_char
    return board

def print_board(board):
    '''Clears the screen prints or re-print all changes'''
    tmp = sp.call('clear')
    for row in board:
        print ' '.join(row)

board = create_board()
print_board(board)

while True:
    '''Main loop'''
    choice = raw_input('What do you want to do? ')
    print_board(board)
    if choice == 'move':
        '''Moves the player. Empties the cell previously occupid,
            adds/subtracts 1 from the player location,
            and then reprints the board'''
        direction = raw_input('Which way do you want to move? ')
        if direction == 'up':
            board[plyr_x][plyr_y] = ' '
            plyr_x += -1
            board[plyr_x][plyr_y] = 'o'
            print_board(board)
        elif direction == 'down':
            board[plyr_x][plyr_y] = ' '
            plyr_x += 1
            board[plyr_x][plyr_y] = 'o'
            print_board(board)
        elif direction == 'right':
            board[plyr_x][plyr_y] = ' '
            plyr_y += 1
            board[plyr_x][plyr_y] = 'o'
            print_board(board)
        elif direction == 'left':
            board[plyr_x][plyr_y] = ' '
            plyr_y += -1
            board[plyr_x][plyr_y] = 'o'
            print_board(board)
    elif choice == 'attack':
        print 'There is no one to attack right now.'
    elif choice == 'die':
        plyr_char = '%'
        print_board(board)
        quit()
```

Everything works fine but I want to get rid of the global variables at the top, if that's possible, and write all of the movement code into it's own move() function so I can get rid of the huge if in the main loop. How could you do this?

Comment: Avoiding global variables mostly means not referencing anything not passed as an argument or defined locally within a function or method. Something defined locally in one function can be passed as an argument to others when necessary, so that way neither of them needs to access a global to get their work done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would proceed:

- Use a `main` function
- Move global args there
- Now you *must* pass your args to functions, rather than rely on globals
- Start to add classes which can contain both behaviour and state!

I only implemented a `Player()` class, but I would also create a board class. I will leave that one up to you!

For example, updating the chars in the player position (and his last known position) could be a method of a the `Board` class. Similarly, you could have a method that displays the board, `def print(self)`. And of course, `create_board()` function would become something like `def __init__(self, player, size)`.

I think you'll find this code is quite easy to understand:

```
import subprocess as sp

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, char):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.char = char

    def move(self, direction):
        """ update our position. """
        if direction.lower() == 'left':
            self.y -= 1
        elif direction.lower() == 'right':
            self.y += 1
        elif direction.lower() == 'up':
            self.x -= 1
        elif direction.lower() == 'down':
            self.x += 1


def create_board(player):
    ''' Creates a 10x10 grid of cells'''
    board = []
    for _ in range(10):
        board.append(['-']*10)
    board[player.x][player.y] = player.char
    return board

def print_board(board):
    '''Clears the screen prints or re-print all changes'''
    tmp = sp.call('clear')
    for row in board:
        print ' '.join(row)


def main():
    player = Player(9, 5, 'o')
    board = create_board(player)
    print_board(board)

    while True:
        '''Main loop'''
        choice = raw_input('What do you want to do? ')
        print_board(board)
        if choice == 'move':
            '''Moves the player. Empties the cell previously occupid,
                adds/subtracts 1 from the player location,
                and then reprints the board'''
            direction = raw_input('Which way do you want to move? ')
            if direction in ('up', 'down', 'left', 'right'):
                board[player.x][player.y] = ' '  # Erase
                player.move(direction)
                board[player.x][player.y] = player.char
                print_board(board)
        elif choice == 'attack':
            print 'There is no one to attack right now.'
        elif choice == 'die':
            player.char = '%'
            print_board(board)
            quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I hope that gives you some ideas!

Comment: Awesome! Now I can mess around with passing args to functions and start implementing classes! Thanks! Just one more thing. How can I find the boundary of the map to keep from getting OutOfBount errors or just ending up on the other side of the map?

Comment: The easiest way is to check the `len(board)` (will give you the size of the first dimension... the row, for example) and to check the `len(board[0])` (will give you the number of of the columns in that row.) So once you know board width and height, you can simply check to see if the player.x is (or will be) greater than that value (or less than zero) then don't allow the move.

Comment: Hey, Symmitchry, I've gotten the board class created and it's working fine but I have no idea how to display the player. I can't seem to access the board like board[x][y] anymore so I'm lost.

Comment: Hi @acollection_. I don't think you should edit your original question, since anyone else reading it will have lost the value of my comment, in large part. If you want to continue working on it, you can find me on reddit and we can chat there, and you can share your code using pastebin or something.

Comment: I reverted it back and messaged you on reddit!

Answer (score 0):

This should hopefully work. I think the concept that might be confusing you is passing things to functions, as that is essentially all that I did.

```
import subprocess as sp



def move(plyr_x, plyr_y, board):
    '''Moves the player. Empties the cell previously occupid,
            adds/subtracts 1 from the player location,
            and then reprints the board'''
    direction = raw_input('Which way do you want to move? ')
    if direction == 'up':
            board[plyr_x][plyr_y] = ' '
            plyr_x += -1
            board[plyr_x][plyr_y] = 'o'
            print_board(board)
    elif direction == 'down':
            board[plyr_x][plyr_y] = ' '
            plyr_x += 1
            board[plyr_x][plyr_y] = 'o'
            print_board(board)
    elif direction == 'right':
            board[plyr_x][plyr_y] = ' '
            plyr_y += 1
            board[plyr_x][plyr_y] = 'o'
            print_board(board)
    elif direction == 'left':
            board[plyr_x][plyr_y] = ' '
            plyr_y += -1
            board[plyr_x][plyr_y] = 'o'
            print_board(board)
    return (plyr_x, plyr_y, board)

def create_board(plyr_x, plyr_y, plyr_char):
    ''' Creates a 10x10 grid of cells'''
    board = []
    for _ in range(10):
        board.append(['-']*10)
    board[plyr_x][plyr_y] = plyr_char
    return board

def print_board(board):
    '''Clears the screen prints or re-print all changes'''
    tmp = sp.call('clear')
    for row in board:
        print ' '.join(row)

def main():
    plyr_x, plyr_y = (9,5)
    plyr_char = 'o'
    board = create_board(plyr_x, plyr_y, plyr_char)
    print_board(board)

    while True:
        '''Main loop'''
        choice = raw_input('What do you want to do? ')
        print_board(board)
        if choice == 'move':
            plyr_x, plyr_y, board = move(plyr_x, plyr_y, board)
        elif choice == 'attack':
            print 'There is no one to attack right now.'
        elif choice == 'die':
            plyr_char = '%'
            print_board(board)
            quit()
```

Comment: I was going fine until I tried to move. It throws a global name error with board. Right on the line `board[plyr_x][plyr_y] = ' '` in the move function.

Comment: That's because this code doesn't work. "board" wasn't passed as an argument to the `move` function, so is undefined!

Comment: Thanks Symmitchry, didn't notice that. If you pass in board, and then return the modified board, you should hopefully be in luck :) I've modified the code to reflect this.

Comment: I believe you should also return updated `player_x` and `player_y` values, since you are modifying them inside your function, too. If you wanted to keep a more functional approach, I would suggest separating those two effects: the updating of the board, and the updating of player coords.

Comment: You are correct, and your answer is a more elegant solution. I'll leave this here for posterity and so that beginners can see examples of how they can take simple actions and bring them out into functions.